# Get value from JSONArray

Tags: android, parsing, json

`JSONObject` `obj` looks like this:

`{"data":"Text 1","data2":"Text 2","turnCounter":0,"data3":["0","1","2"]}`

I have been able to retrieve `data`, `data2`, and `turnCounter` but I can't figure out how to get `data3`:

Here is my attempt

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(st);

if (obj.has("data")) {
    retVal.data = obj.getString("data"); //returns Text 1
}
if (obj.has("data2")) {
    retVal.data2 = obj.getString("data2"); //returns Text 2
}
if (obj.has("turnCounter")) {
    retVal.turnCounter = obj.getInt("turnCounter"); // returns 0
}

List<String> allNames = new ArrayList<String>();
JSONArray cast = obj.getJSONArray("data3");
for (int i=0; i<cast.length(); i++) { //does not return 0, 1, or 2
    JSONObject data3 = cast.getJSONObject(i); //"" "" ""
    retVal.data3.set(i, data3.toString()); //"" "" ""
}
```

Can someone please tell me how I can get the value from the `JsonArray data3`?

Please let me know if I need to provide more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do it is:

```
JSONArray cast = obj.getJSONArray("data3");
String[] string_array = new String[]();
for (int i=0; i<cast.length(); i++) {
    string_array[i] = cast.getString(i);
    retVal.data3.set(i, string_array[i]);
}
```

Try this. This will work.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
JSONObject data3 = cast.getJSONObject(i); //
```

to

```
String data3 = cast.getString(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

The array contains strings so you should call `getString(i)` instead of `getObject(i)`:

```
JSONArray cast = obj.getJSONArray("data3");
for (int i=0; i<cast.length(); i++) {
    String data3 = cast.getString(i);
    Log.e("TAG", data3);
}
```